# Replace data dynamically from array in eval()?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I'm trying to replace the value from array.

```
$row= array("id"=>"35", "name"=>"test","first_name"=>"noor","last_name"=>"fathima");

// Eval Statement - 
$row = $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];

eval("\$row = \"$row\";");
//This should return noor fathima
```

I am unable to replace the values. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: I haven't used `eval()` that much, but what are you attempting to replace the values with? According to the [documentation for eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), the string itself would need to have a variable, right? And according to your comments, you're looking to return "noor fathima". If that's the case, eval is not even needed here and you can just `echo $row;`.

Comment: if there is a way to do it without using eval() its almost always the better option

Comment: Another point I want to make here is that once you assigned `$row` like `$row = $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];`, you've completely overwrote your array with just the string `"noor fathima"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a huge fan of `eval()` as it can be a pain, but the main thing is to get all of the right $'s and quotes escaped/unescaped etc.  To get round this I've put the expression into single quotes as this stops any interpretation - until you `eval()` it...

```
$row= array("id"=>"35", "name"=>"test","first_name"=>"noor","last_name"=>"fathima");
eval('$result = $row["first_name"]." ".$row["last_name"];');
echo $result;
```

gives...

```
noor fathima
```

Comment: Your answer work fine but i replace the eval with my variable its not working could you please help me .

Comment: Could you check the code in your question and post exactly what you have tried and I will check.

Comment: @NigalRen`//message dataproces -$result = $row["first_name"]." ".$row["last_name"];
$userData= array(array("id"=>"35", "name"=>"test","first_name"=>"noor","last_name"=>"fathima"));
try {
    foreach($userData as $row){
        //This works - eval('$result = $row["first_name"]." ".$row["last_name"];');
        //When I'm replacing this variable its not working - eval("'".$_REQUEST['message_dataprocessing']."'");
        echo $result;
    }  
} catch (ParseError $e) { echo "Something went wrong".$e;}`

Comment: Ah - I think this is where the problem is - as I'm using a literal you need the single quotes, as your using a variable you don't, so try `eval($_REQUEST['message_dataprocessing']);`

Comment: You are right. I would have tried this.Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

**Why you need** `eval()` here because it is already returning what you want as output?

```
<?php
$row= array("id"=>"35", "name"=>"test","first_name"=>"noor","last_name"=>"fathima");
echo $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/7KTH0